# Rewrite folder using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So this is the original url of the content:

```
site.com/embed/apple/orange/test1.html
```

and i want people to access the content using this format:

```
site.com/premium/a/o/test1/
```

I tried using this in .htaccess but it dosen't work:

```
RewriteRule ^premium/a/o/(.*) embed/apple/orange/([^/]*)\.html
```

Can someone please give me the exact rule that i need?

Comment: The replacement is not a regular expression, so using `([^/]*)` does not make sense – to access matches found by the search pattern in the replacement, you use back references: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule (And escaping the dot is wrong as well.)

Comment: Yes, i get this: Not Found. The requested URL /embed/apple/orange/([^/]*).html was not found on this serv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a group `(.*)` you can use this later with `$1`

```
RewriteRule ^premium/a/o/(.*)$ embed/apple/orange/$1.html
```